# combining pagingData 3 flow with another flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging, kotlin-flow

I have a pagingData flow object and i want to combine it with a different flow of fused location so it will be processed accordingly with each item of the pagingdata list .

```
val point : Flow<Point> 
val pagingDate : Flow<PagingData>
```

i tried to use combine and combineTransform but it seem to not work as when the point is updating app crashes and shows this error message related to pagingData 3 can't be emited twice

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to collect twice from
> pageEventFlow, which is an illegal operation. Did you forget to call
> Flow<PagingData<*>>.cachedIn(coroutineScope)?

what are my options here to transform pagingdata items with streamed data ?

Comment: Can you share your usage of .combine and the overall operator chain against `Flow<PagingData>`?

Answer (score 5):

Just following up here since others may hit this issue although OP didn't update their answer yet.

This is typically due to usage of `.combine` or similar operators which would repeat the latest emitted value from a Flow, causing the same instance to be used twice. To prevent this you can call `.cachedIn(scope)` before `.combine()` so that the Flow is multicasted, giving you a new instance of PagingData with cached data preloaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

For those wondering, it seems like calling `cachedIn(scope)` twice is acceptable as well.

So this code works perfectly fine:-
`pagedFlow = repository.getPagedData().cachedIn(scope).combine(otherFlow) { // Your UI transformations here }.cachedIn(scope)`

Comment: If your transformation is trivial, you may want to be careful of the number of items you are buffering or at least create a smaller scope to cache them in as opposed to viewModelScope... depending on the number of times you expect `.combine()` to trigger

Comment: Yeah, I had tried different solutions for this but unfortunately, my transformations are not trivial (transforming to UI model and adding separators). The other flow used in `.combine()` won't change during paging, it can change only when the user modifies an entry from some other part of the app. So, `combine()` will mainly be called only when paging data loads. I will see if I can try using some other scope for caching though.

Comment: Also, for app performance, I have noticed calling `cachedIn()` after the transformations has significant positive impact. The items being loaded are relatively lightweight (basic data class, no images) but the no. of items can be very large.

Comment: I feel uneasy about it as Paging codelabs say that `cachedIn()` should be used as a terminal operator. Can somebody explain what exactly happens if you call it twice? What are downsides?